# Save Asterisk CDR to an external host

Tags: mysql, asterisk, cdr

I'm trying to save Asterisk's CDR to an external mysql host.
I've modified the the connection details in the FreePBX advanced settings section, 
and I also tried editing the cdr_mysql.conf file in /etc/asterisk,
but FreePBX still can not connect to the external mysql host.
When I'm trying to log into the UCP I get the failed to connect DB with the connection string.
It looks like the string FreePBX tries to connect with is wrong, becuase when I set up a test .NET web site to try and open a connection to mysql it works, but I am using a different syntax in the connection string.
BTW, I can telnet the external host from my pbx machine and I know for sure that this is not a network issue.

How can I have my CDR saved to an external mysql host?

**Edit: I also copied the db structure from the original mysql server so it won't be an issue.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Check connection string, check firewall

You can use

```
mysql -h hostname -u user -ppassword databasename
```

from command line to check connection is really allowed and no firewall.

You can get db access info from /etc/amportal.conf  or /etc/asterisk/freepbx.conf

If you still have issues after that check, you can enable debug in logger.conf

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can connect to the external mysql host using the command line. In the amportal.conf I can see the settings I setup in FreePBX GUI.  Everything seems ok but FreePBX still can not connect.